# Why doesn't CSS render this table properly? The column header is mis-"padded" to it's contents

Tags: css, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle I'm working on here, and in both AppleWebkit and Mozilla the "Employer" column header does not match correctly against the column's contents in regards to spacing.
http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th` elements are centered by default. Give your `th`s a style of `text-align:left`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/29/

Edit:
The reason that you don't see the effect on the other columns is that the `th`s are all wider than the corresponding `td`s, making then fill the column widths. Only the last `th` is narrower.